# Debian alternatives system: programs with the same name and priorities

Tags: debian, alternatives

I can't understand from the `update-alternatives` documentation how the priorities system works.

Suppose that I want `/usr/bin/node` to point to `nodejs` for nodejs applications and to an amateur radio program, called `node`, in other cases. I have to say:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node nodejs /usr/bin/nodejs 100 --slave /usr/share/man/...
```

Suppose I have 2 programs that expect `/usr/bin/node` to be different things, first - nodejs, second - amateur radio. How would they determine which one to use?

What's the role of priority in this process?

ADDITION: Note, that `npm`, nodejs package manager, expects nodejs command to be called `node`, thus I have to install nodejs as `node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any time, `/usr/bin/node` can only be one of the programs. The alternatives mechanism is a way to choose which one it is.

Priorities control which one is the default when both are installed. They don't offer a way to somehow have both and select between the two based on what other program called this one.

When programs call each other by name, there can only be a single program by a given name that comes first on the search path. You should disambiguate the `node` command in your programs. [Following Debian](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html), use `nodejs` for Node.js and `ax25-node` for the HAM program. If there's one that it would be really annoying to change, install either the `node` package (which makes `/usr/bin/node` an alias for `ax25-node`) or the `nodejs-legacy` package (which makes `/usr/bin/node` an alias for `nodejs`).

If you really have a lot of programs that call `node` and that can't be changed easily, run them with different `PATH` variables, one containing a directory containing a symbolic link to `ax25-node` and one containing a directory containing a symbolic link to `nodejs`:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/nodejs/bin /usr/local/etc/ax25/bin
ln -s ../../../../bin/nodejs /usr/local/etc/nodejs/bin/node
ln -s ../../../../bin/ax25-node /usr/local/etc/ax25/bin/node

PATH=/usr/local/etc/ax25/bin:$PATH program-using-ax25
PATH=/usr/local/etc/node/bin:$PATH program-using-nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gilles! So, what's the purpose of alternatives system, if it doesn't allow to switch symlink for different programs?

Comment: it does allow to switch the symlink, but only on a system-wide basis, not a per-user basis.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're misunderstanding the role of the alternatives system here.  It is used to provide a simple way to use alternative programs of a similar type.  The usual example, and the one used in the man page is an editor:

> For example, if the text editors ed(1) and nvi(1) are both installed
>   on the system, the alternatives system will cause the generic name
>   /usr/bin/editor to refer to /usr/bin/nvi by default.

In your case, `node` refers to two completely different applications.

If both are installable from the main Debian repository then chances are that one of the package maintainers will have named their executable so that it doesn't clash with the other. For example, the binary for the radio application could have been renamed to `/usr/bin/node_radio` so that it doesn't clash with the Node.js `/usr/bin/node`.

On the other hand, if you're compiling the amateur radio `node` yourself, you must ensure that you either alter the compilation so that it doesn't create the same name binary or ensure that it is installed into a different path, such as `/usr/local/bin/node`.  If you opt for the latter, then which `node` is executed when you type it at the command prompt depends on the search order in your `$PATH` variable.  If the *wrong* one is executed, you'll have to enter the full path to run it: `/usr/local/bin/node`.

In any case `update-alternatives` doesn't help you here.

All the above is only an example as a quick check with `apt-get download node` followed by `dpkg --contents node_0.3.2-7.4_all.deb` shows that the amateur radio `node` is installed as `/usr/sbin/ax25-node` with a link from `/usr/sbin/node` to the executable. Node.js installs `/usr/bin/nodejs` therefore the two will never clash.